# question from Russian Olympiad on 1985

Tags: inequality, contest-math

This question is from Russian  Olympiad on 1985:

Define: $a_1=a,b_1=b,c_1=c,d_1=d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are unequal numbers. Define $a_{n+1}=a_n-b_n,b_{n+1}=b_n-c_n$, $c_{n+1}=c_n-d_n,d_{n+1}=d_n-a_n$.

Prove that for some $n$ we have at least one of $a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n$ greater than 1985.

The book gives this solution:

If the resulted numbers after n times pushing are $a_n, b_n, c_n , d_n$, (n≥1),then we must have:

$a_n+ b_n+ c_n + d_n=0$

and:

$a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2≥2(a^2_{n-1}+b^2_{n-1}+c^2_{n-1}+d^2_{n-1})$

I could not understand the solution. Can someone explain it?

Comment: I cannot understand the problem statement.

Comment: $a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2$ increases more than 2 times each time one press the button, so can be made arbitrary large, say $>1985^2*4$, then, by pigeonhole principle, ... )

Comment: "15.  A move replaces the real numbers a, b, c, d by a-b, b-c, c-d, d-a. If a, b, c, d are not all equal, show that at least one of the numbers can exceed 1985 after a finite number of moves. " [here](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/aditya/www.kalva.demon.co.uk/soviet/sov85.html)

Comment: Try using induction to prove  ${a_{n}}^2+{b_{n}}^2+{c_{n}}^2+{d_{n}}^2 \geq 2({a^2_{n−1}}+{b^2_{n−1}}+{c^2_{n−1}}+{d^2_{n−1}})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a_n^2=(a_{n-1}-b_{n-1})^2$, etc.

We also have that 
$(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}+d_{n-1})^2=0$ or 
$a_{n-1}^2+b_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}^2+d_{n-1}^2=-(2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}+2a_{n-1}c_{n-1}+2a_{n-1}d_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}c_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}d_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}d_{n-1})$

Combining the two identities:
$a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2=2(a_{n-1}^2+b_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}^2+d_{n-1}^2)-(2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}+2a_{n-1}d_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}c_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}d_{n-1})=3(a_{n-1}^2+b_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}^2+d_{n-1}^2)+2a_{n-1}c_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}d_{n-1}=2(a_{n-1}^2+b_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}^2+d_{n-1}^2)+(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})^2+(b_{n-1}+d_{n-1})^2$

Now we see that we can make this sum arbitrary large and greater than $36\cdot 1985^2$ so at least one of the squares is greater than $(3\cdot 1985)^2$.

If that's a square of a positive number, we are done. If that square is a negative number, the sum of the other three numbers should be greater than $3 \cdot 1985$ so at least one of them is greater than $1985$

Comment: You showed that wlog $a_n^2\ge1985^2$, but $a_n$ could be negative.

Comment: How did you  find 1985?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: fair point, I've made some updates to the answer